# Same thing works on terminal but not in java Runtime while using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, java

I have a Java project which I developed in windows. Now, I want to make it platform independent.

A part of the project is: it takes a c program and executes. takes input from file and gives output in file, then compares the output file with another file and gives a result.

At first I have a class which runs the `.cpp` file and produce executable file. As far I know, the command for this work is same in both windows and ubuntu and that is:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o <name of executable file> <path of .cpp file>
```

Using the above command, it works good using terminal. But while implementing the same thing in code, it is giving compilation error. That means the following errors:

```
g++: fatal error: no input files
```

See the image to be more clear:

[image]

#### My code:

```
package judgecpp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

class CodeCompile implements Runnable, RunInCmd {

    Thread compilerThread;
    private final File fileCPP;
    
    public File file;
    public boolean errorHas;

    public CodeCompile(File fileCPP) {
        this.fileCPP = fileCPP;

        file = new File(String.format("compiledFile%d", CodeProcessing.getNewFileNumber()));
        compilerThread = new Thread(this, "compilerThread");
    }

    @Override
    public Process cmdRun(String command) throws IOException {
        Runtime rt;
        Process pr;
        rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        pr = rt.exec(command);
        return pr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            String command = String.format("g++ -std=c++11 -o \"" + file.toString() + "\" \"" + fileCPP.toString() + "\"");
//            if(VerdictGiver.os.equals("uni")) command = String.format("g++ -std=c++11 \"" + fileCPP.toString() + "\" -o \"" + file.toString() + "\"");
//            command = "pwd";
            System.out.println("Code Compile: "+command);
            System.out.println("OS: "+VerdictGiver.os);
            Process pr = cmdRun(command);
            Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
            String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
            System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + s);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getErrorStream()));
            
            errorHas = false;
            System.out.println("Compile Error Stream starts -----------------------------------------");
            while (input.readLine() != null) {
                System.out.println(input.readLine());
                errorHas = true;
            }
            System.out.println("Compile Error Stream ends -------------------------------------------");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
//            Logger.getLogger(CodeCompile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I am stacked here for a long time.

#### Update:

I got the solution, but don't know why it works. Instead of line:

```
String command = String.format("g++ -std=c++11 -o \"" + file.toString() + "\" \"" + fileCPP.toString() + "\"");
```

I used the following line:

```
String command = String.format("cmd /c \"g++ -std=c++11 -o \"" + file.toString() + "\" \"" + fileCPP.toString() + "\"\"");
```

That means generated string would be like:

```
cmd /c "g++ -std=c++11 -o "compiledFile0" "Submissions/20_masd_0_2015_09_14_01_09_58.cpp""
```

---

But in case of running the program, none of the following strings is working:

[image]

First (this one works fine in terminal):

```
"./compiledFile0"<"/home/mamun/Desktop/ContestSettings/icpc2015-data/artichoke/12.in">"output1.txt"
```

Second:

```
cmd /c ""./compiledFile0"<"/home/mamun/Desktop/ContestSettings/icpc2015-data/artichoke/12.in">"output1.txt""
```

Third:

```
cmd /c ""compiledFile0"<"/home/mamun/Desktop/ContestSettings/icpc2015-data/artichoke/12.in">"output1.txt""
```

Fourth:

```
"compiledFile0"<"/home/mamun/Desktop/ContestSettings/icpc2015-data/artichoke/12.in">"output1.txt"
```

But this time no luck, need help.

Comment: Before trying to answer there's a more existential question, namely, why write a Java program that builds and executes a C++ file, especially if the goal is "platform independence"? (I'll even put aside the perennial argument about whether _either_ language is capable of producing such a condition.)

Comment: I am developing a contest manager. And I don't know other language as JAVA and C/C++. However, If you have any question related to the question above, then comment here, otherwise don't annoy us. @zerobandwidth